# How to implements a HorizontalPullTorefreshLayout in Android?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, pull-to-refresh

I want to implements a HorizontalPullToRefreshLayout. Now I am planed to extends FrameLayout and make it can host only one child, but if the child is a scrollable view, like ListView or RecyclerView, I don't when to pass the TouchEvent or intercept it. Is there any method to determine whether a child can scroll?  Please share your idea of implements this HorizontalPullToRefreshView. My Project minSdk is 15.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: You have to use lib for HorizontalPullTorefreshLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [ViewCompat.canScrollHorizontally](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#canScrollHorizontally(android.view.View,%20int)) to check if the child view can be scrolled or not.

Comment: yes. I just find view.canScrollHorizontally(int direction).